# Is it possible to pass data from Android Wear 2.0 watch to an IOS (Iphone) app?

Tags: ios, swift, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

I wrote an Android Wear 2.0 that pass data to a phone side using Wearable DataAPI.
This works nice when the phone side is Android based.

Is it possible to write an IOS app that can accept data from a watch using Wearable DataAPI ? (in swift)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do that using [Google Wearable DataAPI](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html), but you can look at [this API](https://github.com/ibm-wearables-sdk-for-mobile/ibm-wearables-swift-sdk) for example. Of course, you need implement support for iPhone app yourself.

Comment: The swift API doesnt contain a connector for android wear.
How exactly is this a solution to the problem ?